# pie chart d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am creating a pie chart with json data .. arcs are creating fine but they are not taking color and text i am giving 
it parsing the json data taking the values but not returning different colors for different names...and similar is the case with text too .. but when i try to print in console it prints ... 
... here is my code

```
        function drawPiechart( dataurl, selector ){

            var width = 130,
            height = 130,
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

            var color = d3.scale.category20();

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius - 10)
                .innerRadius(0);
            /*var arc1 = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius + 10)
                .innerRadius(0);*/

            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .sort(null)
                .value(function(d) { return d.workload; });

            var svg = d3.select(selector).append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height)
              .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

            d3.json(dataurl, function(error, data) {
            console.log(data);
              data.HubActivity.hubWorkloadList.forEach(function(d) {
                d.workload = +d.workload;
                console.log(d.workload);
              });
            /*function animateFirstStep(){
                d3.select(this)
                  .transition()            
                    .delay(0)            
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("d",arc1)
                    .each("end", animateSecondStep);
            };
            function animateSecondStep(){
                d3.select(this)
                  .transition()
                    .duration(1000)
                    .attr("d", arc);
            };*/
              var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
                  .data(pie(data.HubActivity.hubWorkloadList))
                .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "arc");

              g.append("path")
                  .attr("d", arc)
                  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.trName); });
                  // .on("mouseover", animateFirstStep);

              g.append("text")
                  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                  .style("fill","black")
                  .text(function(d) { console.log( d.workload); });

            }); 
        };





        drawPiechart( "../data/pie0.json", "#workload");
```

here is my json data

```
{
"HubActivity": {        
    "hubWorkloadList": [
        {
            "trName": "addAccessDateValue",
            "workload": "20.00"
        },
        {
            "trName": "addAddress",
            "workload": "10.00"
        },
        {
            "trName": "getAccessDateValue",
            "workload": "10.00"
        },
        {
            "trName": "getAddress",
            "workload": "10.00"
        },
        {
            "trName": "searchCategory",
            "workload": "10.00"
        },
        {
            "trName": "searchCategoryHierarchy",
            "workload": "10.00"
        },
        {
            "trName": "updateAccessDateValue",
            "workload": "30.00"
        },
        {
            "trName": "updateAddressNote",
            "workload": "10.00"
        },
        {
            "trName": "updateAddressValue",
            "workload": "10.00"
        },
        {
            "trName": "updateAlert",
            "workload": "10.00"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

please tell where is the error coming ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `d3.layout.pie` function creates a new data structure that contains the information needed to draw the chart at the top level. This is what you're working with when choosing colors and appending text and this is why it doesn't work -- the data you're looking for are no longer where they were before.

In each element that `pie()` returns, there is a `.data` member that contains the original data. Using this, you can access the information you're looking for. That is, you need to change

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.trName); });
```

to

```
.style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.trName); });
```

and similarly for the text.